# error to deploy a shiny app with rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, rpivottable

I'm trying to deploy a shiny application. The code of the app is:

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)


ui <- fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                titlePanel(windowTitle = "Archivo de riesgo",
                           title =
                             div(
                               tags$img(
                                 src = "logof.png",
                                 style = "margin:10px 10px"
                               ),
                               "Archivo de riesgo"
                             )
                ),

                mainPanel(
                  h6("Nota: número de riesgos en miles; valor asegurado y prima en millones."),
                  rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("OverallPivot")
                )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  output$OverallPivot <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data = base_final_compañias, rows="seguro", cols="año", vals = "valor", aggregatorName = "Sum", rendererName = "Horizontal Bar Chart", inclusions=list(`Descripción`=list("Número de riesgos")))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I use `rsconnect::deployApp('path/to/your/app')` for deploy my app. But the following error appears.

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : there is no package called ‘rpivotTable’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Ejecución interrumpida
```

as shown in this link https://csarmiento.shinyapps.io/riesgos/.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: The package is already installed and the error still occurs.

Comment: Have you tried to close and re-open R, remove rpivotTable with remove.packages and reinstall it ?

Comment: The error still occurs. I Have the following warning message
`Failed to parse C:/Users/csarmiento/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpA9cCql/file2868544570e4/app.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.`